# How to organize parts of a project that use common files?

Tags: c++, git, repository, organization

I'm developing a C++ project. My project consists of two parts: backend and GUI. Both of them written in C++. Now I've finished developing the first part - backend. Now I want to start developing the GUI part, but I don't know how to organize git repositories and folders structure. Now I have a single repository with only backend project. Am I supposed to create another repository for GUI? The problem also is that backend and GUI project will use common libraries and common header files. So, if is it good idea to create a new repository, then how can I share common files between projects? Maybe you know some open source projects that also consist of multiple parts and have common files? I would be glad to learn how they solved that problem. Hope for your help!

P.S: I use CMake build system and CLion IDE. Backend and GUI are compiled by different compilers, but CMake doesn't support using of different compilers in one project. So, I anyway have to separate CMake projects.

Comment: Common code can go in its own library. then it is Mono repo versus multi repo.

Comment: If you're working in an environment that supports workspaces with multiple projects (like e.g. Visual Studio), then you could use one workspace for everything and then one project for the backend, one project for the GUI, and one (library, possibly DLL) project for the common code. If there's a tight coupling between the GUI and the backend, then I would suggest one single repository for the whole workspace, including the library. Otherwise one main repository for the workspace, and Git sub-modules for the different projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would typically do with common libraries or any "generic" code is place them into their own repository.  You can then pull the shared libraries into your other projects (backend and GUI) as Git submodules.

One great advantage of submodules is that the link in your parent project (GUI or backend) tracks the specific revision used in any commit made to the parent project, so there is never any confusion about which version of the common library was used in any particular version of the parent project.

More detail on submodules can be found here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules